# Eclipse - Project Referencing another Project instead of .jar File

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, ivy

I have a Java project in eclipse:

`Project A` contains an Ivy dependency on `Project B`.

Locally, I checked out and made changes to `Project B`. I then wanted to test the new functionality from `Project B` in `Project A`, so I added `Project B` as a project dependency of `Project A` by adding it to the Java Build Path (Java Build Path->Projects->Add...).

I no longer wish to have that dependency on `Project A`, but simply removing it from the Projects Build Path hasn't worked. With that dependency removed, I would expect that any references to the new local code would result in a syntax error, since those changes have not been incorporated into a new artifact for Ivy to pull in.

How can I remove any references to `Project B` from `Project A`? I've tried deleting both projects and re-checking them out and that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to resolve this issue is to:

1. Close `Project B` in eclipse.
2. On `Project A` run Project-Clean
3. Resolve Ivy dependencies on `Project A`

Now the dependencies from `Project B` should use the Ivy artifact rather than the local changes.